# Automating the task and Autorefreshing the web pages for every 10 minutes

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, web-applications, webbrowser-control

Please guide me how can I achieve the below task.

I have to monitor 5 web pages every 15 minutes.

Say the webpages names are `A.html`,`B.html`,`C.html`,`D.html`,`E.html`.

I am opening each IE(internet explorer) web page manually every 15 minutes and checking whether it is up or down.

Can we make this automated, I want a single link on which if I click it should open all the 5 web pages and autorefresh them for every 10 minutes.

Please suggest me any possible web links or websites or tutorials that can help me in this case.

Thanks,
Srihari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var refreshPages = new Array("http://www.microsoft.com", "http://www.bing.com", "http://www.apple.com");
    var refreshRate = 5000; //milliseconds

    function refreshWindows() {
        for (index in refreshPages)
        {
            window.open(refreshPages[index], "refreshwindow" + index, "");
        }

        setTimeout("refreshWindows();", refreshRate);
    }
```

You can call this function on a button-click for example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="refreshWindows();return false;">start monitoring</a>
```

As you can see, I declate an array of uri's that I want to open and I also declare a refreshRate (Milliseconds).
In the refreshWindows-method I loop through my array and call the window.open-method for each URI. The most important thing here is that I also provide a name for each window (refreshWindowINDEX). So the next time I call the window.open-method with a name that I've already used, the browser will open that uri in the window with that name. I call the setTimeout-method, so that JavaScript waits (in this example 5 seconds) and calls the refreshWindows-method again. Opening the same set of uri's in the same windows.